# Why variable name and datatype name is allowed with function but not with keyword?

Tags: c++, variables, syntax, malloc, new-operator

Previously we have used `malloc` for dynamic memory allocation,

```
struct node* node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

It worked fine.

While doing re-factoring I changed it to,

```
struct node* node = new node;
```

And it gives me error,

> Error 1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'node'

Why same variable `node` name works fine with function (malloc) while does not work with (new).

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
struct node* node = new node;
             ^^^^
```

As soon as the compiler sees the underlined part, the token `node` refers to that variable. So when it processes `new node`, it is `new name_of_a_variable` which doesn't make sense. To fix this, you could call your variable something different (this is a good idea anyway).

The malloc version has no problem because you never use `node` on its own, you always use `struct node` which is unambiguously a type name.

Comment: Shouldn't compiler understand the context?

Comment: No. You can only have one meaning for an identifier in the same scope. Sometimes one overtakes the other ("shadowing") and sometimes it causes a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Confirming the other answer (which says it was the use of the keyword
`struct` that enabled your `malloc` example to compile),
this program compiled and ran on https://ideone.com using C++14:

```
#include <iostream>
struct node { int x; };
int main()
{
  struct node* node = new struct node;
  node->x = 1;
  std::cout << node->x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

So you *can* use `struct node` as an unambiguous type name in your
particular example.  It really is the same problem and solution
whether you use `node` with `new` or with `malloc`.

But as already pointed out, it would be better to choose different names for your types and your variables.